# Задать разные классы для дочерних элементов меню

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

Проблема в том, что к дочерним элементам Меню применяются один и тот же класс - `mega-sub-menu`. Например, "Море" и "горы" я хочу сверстать с черным background а их дочерние элементы с белым background. Как мне быть?

```css
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu ul,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu p,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu img,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu div,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu a {
  color: #666;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: auto;
  top: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  left: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 1.5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: none;
  overflow: visible;
  display: block;
  min-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: auto;
  clip: auto;
  height: auto;
  outline: none;
  visibility: inherit;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu ul:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu p:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu img:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu div:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu a:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu ul:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu p:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu img:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu div:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu a:after {
  display: none;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu table,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu td,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu tr,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu th {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu ul.mega-sub-menu,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu a.mega-menu-link {
  -moz-transition: none;
  -o-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -ms-box-shadow: none;
  -o-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip: auto;
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: auto;
  left: auto;
  line-height: 1.5;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  outline: none;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  top: auto;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  visibility: inherit;
  width: auto;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu ul.mega-sub-menu:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu a.mega-menu-link:before,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu ul.mega-sub-menu:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item:after,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu a.mega-menu-link:after {display: none;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu {
    padding: 0;}}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu a.mega-menu-link {
  display: inline;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu input,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu img {
  max-width: 100%;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item > ul.mega-sub-menu {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 1;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu.mega-no-js li.mega-menu-item:hover > ul.mega-sub-menu,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu.mega-no-js li.mega-menu-item:focus > ul.mega-sub-menu,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item.mega-toggle-on > ul.mega-sub-menu,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item.mega-menu-megamenu.mega-toggle-on ul.mega-sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  float: left;
  display: flex;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item a[class^='dashicons']:before {
  font-family: dashicons;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-disable-link > a.mega-menu-link {
  cursor: default;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item a.mega-menu-link:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  font-family: dashicons;
  position: static;
  margin: 0 6px 0 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: inherit;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-menu-item.mega-hide-text a.mega-menu-link:before {
  margin: 0;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-align-bottom-left.mega-toggle-on > a.mega-menu-link {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-align-bottom-right > ul.mega-sub-menu {right: 0;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu li.mega-align-bottom-right.mega-toggle-on > a.mega-menu-link {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -ms-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -o-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu.mega-menu-item {
  position: static;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item {
  margin: 0 0px 0 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item.mega-item-align-right {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item.mega-toggle-on > a.mega-menu-link,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:hover,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:focus {
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #fff;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item.mega-current-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item.mega-current-menu-ancestor > a.mega-menu-link {
  background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link {
  border-top: 0px solid #fff;
  border-left: 0px solid #fff;
  border-right: 0px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 11px 23px 0px 23px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -ms-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -o-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item {
    display: list-item;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    border: 0;}
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item.mega-item-align-right {float: none;}
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px;}}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu {
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -ms-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  -o-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background: #baaca3;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#c1b6ae), to(#baaca3));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c1b6ae, #baaca3);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #c1b6ae, #baaca3);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #c1b6ae, #baaca3);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #c1b6ae, #baaca3);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFC1B6AE', endColorstr='#FFBAACA3');
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 0px solid #fff;
  border-left: 0px solid #fff;
  border-right: 0px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
  left: 0;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu {
    float: left;
    position: static;
    width: 100% !important;}}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-1-of-1 {width: 100%;}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-1-of-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-2-of-2 {
  width: 100%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-1-of-3 {
  width: 33.33333%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-2-of-3 {
  width: 66.66667%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-3-of-3 {
  width: 100%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-1-of-4 {
  width: 25%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-2-of-4 {
  width: 50%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-3-of-4 {
  width: 75%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-4-of-4 {
  width: 100%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-1-of-5 {
  width: 20%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-2-of-5 {
  width: 40%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-3-of-5 {
  width: 60%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-4-of-5 {
  width: 80%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-5-of-5 {
  width: 100%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-1-of-6 {
  width: 16.66667%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-2-of-6 {
  width: 33.33333%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-3-of-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-4-of-6 {
  width: 66.66667%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-5-of-6 {
  width: 83.33333%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-6-of-6 {
  width: 100%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-1-of-7 {
  width: 14.28571%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-2-of-7 {
  width: 28.57143%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-3-of-7 {
  width: 42.85714%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-4-of-7 {
  width: 57.14286%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-5-of-7 {
  width: 71.42857%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-6-of-7 {
  width: 85.71429%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-7-of-7 {
  width: 100%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-1-of-8 {
  width: 12.5%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-2-of-8 {
  width: 25%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-3-of-8 {
  width: 37.5%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-4-of-8 {
  width: 50%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-5-of-8 {
  width: 62.5%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-6-of-8 {
  width: 75%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-7-of-8 {
  width: 87.5%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-columns-8-of-8 {
  width: 100%;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item ul.mega-sub-menu {
  clear: both;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item ul.mega-sub-menu {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item ul.mega-sub-menu {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item {
  color: #666;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item.mega-menu-clear {
  clear: left;
  /* Widget titles */
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item h4.mega-block-title {
  color: #555;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  border-top: 0px solid #555;
  border-left: 0px solid #555;
  border-right: 0px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #555;
  /* Second level menu item */
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  border-top: 0px solid #555;
  border-left: 0px solid #555;
  border-right: 0px solid #555;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #555;
  /* Second level menu item hover */
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:hover,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:focus {
  color: #3f3f3f;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  /* Third level menu item */
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: block;
  /* Third level menu item hover */
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:hover,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:focus {
  color: #3f3f3f;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu {
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -ms-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    -o-border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  }
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li.mega-menu-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-megamenu > ul.mega-sub-menu > li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu {
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 0px solid #fff;
  border-left: 0px solid #fff;
  border-right: 0px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
  background: #2f3943;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu {
    float: left;
    position: static;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item {
    clear: both;
  }
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item a.mega-menu-link {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(241, 241, 241, 0);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 40px 0 40px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item:first-child a.mega-menu-link {
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item:first-child a.mega-menu-link {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;}}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item:last-child a.mega-menu-link {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
  #mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item:last-child a.mega-menu-link {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item a.mega-menu-link:hover,
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item a.mega-menu-link:focus {
  background-color: #2f3943;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#mega-menu-wrap-primary-menu #mega-menu-primary-menu > li.mega-menu-flyout ul.mega-sub-menu li.mega-menu-item ul.mega-sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 45px;
  visibility: inherit;
}
  
/** Thursday 24th of March 2016 04:19:37 PM **/
```

```html
<ul id="mega-menu-primary-menu" class="mega-menu mega-menu-horizontal" data-event="click" data-effect="fade" data-second-click="close" data-document-click="collapse" data-reverse-mobile-items="true" data-vertical-behaviour="standard" data-breakpoint="1040">
  <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-current-menu-item mega-page_item mega-page-item-821 mega-current_page_item mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-876" id="mega-menu-item-876"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-menu-item-has-children mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-536 mega-toggle-on" id="mega-menu-item-536"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/">Направления</a>
    <ul class="mega-sub-menu" style="">
      <li class="mega-color000 mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-has-children mega-menu-item-520" id="mega-menu-item-520"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/sea/">Море</a>
        <ul class="mega-sub-menu">
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-1089" id="mega-menu-item-1089"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/sea/anakliya/">Анаклия</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-521" id="mega-menu-item-521"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/sea/batumi/">Батуми</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-791" id="mega-menu-item-791"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/sea/kobuleti/">Кобулети</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-1088" id="mega-menu-item-1088"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/sea/ureki/">Уреки</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="mega-podmenu mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-has-children mega-menu-item-783" id="mega-menu-item-783"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/gori/">Горы</a>
        <ul class="mega-sub-menu">
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-1096" id="mega-menu-item-1096"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/gori/1090-2/">Бакуриани</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-1112" id="mega-menu-item-1112"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/gori/kazbegi/">Казбеги</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-784" id="mega-menu-item-784"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/gori/mestia/">Местиа</a>
          </li>
          <li class="mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-location mega-menu-item-1106" id="mega-menu-item-1106"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="http://sunnyge.com/location/gori/ushguli/">Ушгули</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>

  </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>

</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: вот в таком направлении можно попробовать - https://jsfiddle.net/vL2g6v5a/

Comment: @splash58 похоже это то, что мне нужно. Не могли бы Вы ответить, на мой вопрос, описав, что именно Вы изменили, огромное спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно применить ко всем классам `mega-sub-menu` черный фон, а вот к дочерним уже белый:

```
.mega-sub-menu {
  background-color: #000;
}
.mega-sub-menu .mega-sub-menu {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

В итоге второй селектор перекрывать первый, и выводится как приоритетный.